# Using the output of a function as an input of another function

Tags: python, function, variables

Suppose i have function like this.

```
def funA(a,b):
 if a>5:
   c=a+b
 if a<5:
   c=a-b
 return c
```

So is it possible for me to use the variable C outside in another function like this? Is this a correct way?

```
def fun(foo)
 if foo>5:
   foo +=c
 return foo
```

Comment: This is covered in almost any tutorial on functions.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I wanted to ask this as a Basic because am stuck in iterating over Tensors of a featuremap where face this error

Comment: ... but you accepted an answer that is not dependent on tensors or featuremaps.  The needed information is in the tutorials.  The closure vote stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use the returned value as a parameter

heres an example:

```
def funcA(x):
    return x

def funcB(y):
    return y

#pass to function
funcB(funcA(1))

#store to variables
z = funcA(1)
```

heres how it could apply to your case:

first off you're only going to get one value from this since a cant be less than and greater than 5 at the same time, so im going to modify the function to give you both values as a tuple:

```
def funA(a,b):
  return (a+b,a-b)

def funB(c,d):
    print(c,d)

funB(funA(1,2)[0], funA(1,2)[1])
```

If you look closely, `funA` returns a tuple of those values so you can access each one using their `index`; first index is 0, and second index is 1 hence: `funA(1,2)[0]` and `funA(1,2)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You return the value, and you can store the results of a function call in a variable and use it again. A very short example. You should probably go do a python intro course.

```
def add(a, b):
  return a + b

def mult(a, b):
  return a * b

def add_and_mult(a, b):
  added = add(a, b)
  multed = mult(a, b)
  return add(added, multed)
```

Comment: what if the function has multiple Returns nested . I have added the edt. Cna you please check if possible

Comment: each time the function is called it returns a single value. if you use an "if" to return one value or the other, the one you return is the one available to the calling function.